# Is there a .NET 4.5 equivalent to: Storagefile.Openasync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm falling in love with async and await, however I cannot figure out how to await a file open without using Task.Run. There seems to be an [API in WRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync). Where is the .NET 4.5 equivalent? I ask because if i'm accessing a UNC share on a remote machine this has the potential to block for a very long time if the machine is down or not responding to network requests for some reason. It seems like such a big over site.

```
using (FileStream stream = await Task.Run(() => new FileStream(@"c:\temp\text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true)))
{
  byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[stream.Length];    
  await stream.ReadAsync(bytesToRead, 0, bytesToRead.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return bytesToRead;
}
```

Comment: Calling `new FileStream` will not begin reading from the stream, there is no reason to use `Task.Run`. Your code is already asynchronous when it hits `await stream.ReadAsync`, which actually starts reading from the stream.

Comment: I disagree:

    `Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
  new FileStream(@"\\10.1.1.2\c$\test", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true);
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
  Trace.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
finally
{
  Trace.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }`
The network path was not found.
00:00:38.5445538

This takes 30 seconds. Under the hood it ends up calling: [link]http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs which is syncronous.

Comment: I just tried opening a handle on a 4GB file, it took me 00:00:00.0004030. I called it like so: `var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\HugeFile.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);`

Comment: That file is local. Try opening a network share via a unc that doesn't exist as I did in my sample. It will take a long time.

Comment: Are you sure the amount of time being taken is consumed by the opening of the handle? i'd assume its the network wire that would be the culprit.

Comment: If you are on the wire you have done I/O and it should be done async, not sync.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though file opens are asynchronous at the device driver level, there is no Win32 API for an asynchronous file open. So that's why there's no .NET equivalent; I don't know for sure but I suspect that the WinRT API is faking an asynchronous operation by queueing it to the thread pool.

So, the best solution is to do a similar workaround: use `Task.Run`. I'd wrap all the `FileStream` code in `Task.Run`, though.

Comment: [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` doesn't asynchronously open the handle to the file?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: No, it (synchronously) opens the file handle with asynchronous operations enabled.

Comment: Just to add a little more information after some googling. 

"I sent this thread off to the I/O manager folks as a feature suggestion. Being able to open files on the network without the delay could be useful, though it's hard to associate a file which doesn't yet exist with a completion port, so it would probably end up being an event driven process if it should happen."

[link](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/2006-08/msg00308.html)

Comment: (In context of not having asynchronous file handles) *"Then again, it must not be soooo bad since we've gotten along okay without
it this long, and not just on Windows."*, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experiences using https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge for `async` methods without `Task.Run`, although syntactically it looks somewhat similar, it is much safer.

Comment: While that looks really nice it doesn't solve the problem of needing to block a thread while opening a file. IO shouldn't need to block a thread period. They provide these calls for reading and writing a file, but not opening. It seems silly.

Comment: I don't see how will that help here: `AsyncBridge` seems to be about waiting synchronously for async method, the problem here is that there is no asynchronous alternative to an operation that can take a long time.

Comment: It has an asynchronous fire and forget api... Guess it isn't documented, oh well.