# IOException in Async Function Blocking UI Thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

With the following code, if *"The network path was not found"* it completely blocks the UI for up to 15 seconds. If I replace the code with `Await Task.Delay(5000)` it doesn't. It's like the open `FileStream` is not happening asynchronously...

How can I handle this scenario without blocking the UI?

For info, I'm trying to read a one line (1kb) text file asynchronously.

```
Private Async Function getDataAsync(filepath As String, ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Dim data as string
    Try
        Using sourceStream As New FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                             FileShare.Read, bufferSize:=4096, useAsync:=True)
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(sourceStream)
            data = Await reader.ReadLineAsync()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        data = ex.Message
    End Try

    Return data
End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a .NET 4.5 equivalent to: Storagefile.Openasync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513880/is-there-a-net-4-5-equivalent-to-storagefile-openasync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the execution is always synchronous up until the first `Await`.

Try something like this:

```
Private Async Function getDataAsync(filepath As String, ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Return Await Task.Run(Function()
        Dim data as string
        Try
            Using sourceStream As New FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                                 FileShare.Read, bufferSize:=4096, useAsync:=True)
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(sourceStream)
                data = Await reader.ReadLineAsync()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            data = ex.Message
        End Try
        Return data
    End Function)
End Function
```